# Is there an F# operator to express this function?

Tags: f#, operators

I've got the following code:

`let funcsAppliedToData data = funcs |> Seq.map (fun f -> f data)`

Is there an operator to express the function defined in the brackets (or a neater way of writing the whole line, for that matter)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can rewrite this using a partial function application of the `|>` operator. The function you have:

```
 (fun f -> f data)
```

Can also be written using the pipe operator:

```
 (fun f -> data |> f)
```

You can treat the operator as a function:

```
 (fun f -> (|>) data f)
```

Now you could use partial function application:

```
 ((|>) data)
```

This answers your question, but I don't think I would use this in practice. Writing the function explicitly may be a couple of characters longer, but I just find it much more readable. The pipe operator is not usually used in the above way and so anyone reading the code will basically have to reverse the process I described here to understand what's going on.